# How to reset Elasticsearch completely from Windows 10 PC including the accounts that I have generated with a elasticsearch-setup-passwords auto

Tags: elasticsearch

I am completely new to using **Elasticsearch** and I am having problems running scripts on my windows 10 PC ever since running the command to generate accounts for ELK stack with passwords.

```
elasticsearch-setup-passwords auto
```

Running to random errors like writing access disabled  to `'missing authentication credentials for REST request'` , I just want to completely reset all these to the state it was after the first time I installed elasticsearch. Because I have tried uninstalling elasticsearch but it does not remove the account information that were generated. Please help me out.

Please note that I am using the Basic version.

Comment: Have you tried wiping C:\Program Files\Elastic\Elasticsearch\data ?

Comment: That's the thing, there's no data folder or any yml files at all in the basic version. now I am stuck and cant run elasticsearch scripts at all